# Acrobat Reader doesn't recognize relative path

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, relative-path, acrobat

I exported an Excel sheet to a tab delimited file (.txt) and now try to batch-import it into a PDF-form via Acrobat Reader Pro DC.
This works perfectly with an action, that imports said .txt, as long, as the path is absolute. Because I want to ship the file and have other people run in as well, I need to have the path relative. My current approach is to change

```
var fileName = "/C/Users/somefancyname/Desktop/export.txt";
this.importTextData(fileName, somerowcounter)
```

to

```
var fileName = "export.txt";
this.importTextData(fileName, somerowcounter)
```

This, unfortunately throws an "Cannot Open File" error. The file I run this script on is on the very same level, as the text file. My only guess would be, that the path is relative to the acrobat app, instead of the document, but I can't help it anymore, as this is my first approach with Acrobat JS, ever.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a hacky way to create a pseudo-relative path. Tested, works!

You simply use the length of the documents filename and substract it from the documents path. This awards you with the basepath of the document.

```
var filenameLength = this.documentFileName.length * -1;
var basePath = this.path.slice(0, filenameLength);
```

You then proceed to use this basepath to create an absoulte path to your files in this place, as if these were relative paths.

```
var fileName = basePath + "export.txt";
var outputFodler = basePath + "/OutputFolder/";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the optional `cPath` parameter of `importTextData` is:

["A relative device-independent path to the text file."](https://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.502.html) Which actually seems quite what what you need. In the examples, however, they give absolute paths.

Can you consider asking the users to provide the path somehow and use it further?

Comment: Talking about "relative" device-independent paths, isn't this exactly what I need?

Comment: @Rufrage - actually you need "relative", not absolute indeed. But somehow in the examples they give "absolute" paths. A bit weird indeed.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. However, my given example works, but the relative way doesn't. Anny suggestions on how I can build an absolute path from the current document?

Comment: Adobe needs to work on either their functions, or correct the documentation. However, it worked by creating a path to the current directory and appending the filename to it. Check my answer, thanks again!